# primefaces datagrid draggable implementation issue with scroll

Tags: primefaces, drag-and-drop, scroll

Hello I have implemented the datagrid draggable example.
However, i have an issue when addding the scroll option to the available cars field.
When i drop the element is dissapers from the view.

```
<p:fieldset id="availableCarsField" legend="AvailableCars" style="overflow: auto">
    <p:dataGrid id="availableCars" var="car" value="#{dndCarsView.cars}" columns="3">
        <p:column>
            <p:panel id="pnl" header="#{car.id}" style="text-align:center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
                    <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/car/#{car.brand}.gif" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>

            <p:draggable for="pnl" revert="true" handle=".ui-panel-titlebar" stack=".ui-panel"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataGrid>
</p:fieldset>
```

Actually, i have found this issue dating from 2011.
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=2173

I don't know if it's fixed yet.
I am using primefaces 4.0.

Thank you, i m here for further explanation.